# Windows embedded standard not a valid win32 c++

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, windows-xp

I'm trying to compile an exe for my old windows machine, but i'm having a problem with the latest version of Visual studios.

Iv set it to win32 application.

Iv set the platform toolset to: Visual Studio 2015 - Windows XP (v140_xp)

I have the windows XP support for c++ installed.

My runtime library is: Multi-threaded Debug (/MTd)

My additional library directory is set to: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\lib;"

Installed the MSVC 2015 C++ redis. on target machine.

Still says its an invalid win32 application.

Target platform: "Window embedded standard, Service pack 3"

After seeing: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36314217/is-not-a-valid-win32-application-on-windows-xp) I'm going to try and custom install visual studios 2012 for just its c++ for XP so I can tell it to build with that compiler.

Is this just because of the new changes to the Windows SDK being difficult with windows xp, or is this something to do with it being embedded standard?

Comment: My advice:  Run away from Windows XP as fast as you can.

Comment: @edtheprogrammerguy Would love too. But the device I'm writing this program for ONLY works on embedded standard. Period.

Comment: this is windows embeded, not desktop XP- I am not sure but you need to use some earlier Visual Studio versions (or earlier toolchains), for example for Windows CE i'am able to use only Visual Studio 2005 (maybe 2008 would work too). See here for more details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms950428.aspx

Comment: are you targetting x64 or x86?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After installing visual studios 2012 creating a new project and copying my code, I compared the properties between the two versions. They were nearly the same except for a few properties, one property being;

Linker->System->Subsystem Was set to: "Console (/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE)" In VS2012

After making the change in vs2015, the application began working.

Comment: As a note: vs2015 had this set to: SUBSYSTEM:NATIVE